# Removing value from array on specific location

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I realise there is a lot of topics on this subject but I believe this one is different:

The goal is to get an value from an array on a random location then delete this value.

I use this part by John Resig (the creator of jQuery) to remove an element but it doesn't seem to listen to the location I give it

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(from, to) {
var rest = this.slice((to || from) + 1 || this.length);
this.length = from < 0 ? this.length + from : from;
return this.push.apply(this, rest);
};
```

this is how I use it

```
var elements = ['#1','#2','#3','#4']
var R1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length),
E1 = elements.slice(R1,1)
elements.remove(R1)
var R2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length),
E2 = elements.slice(R2,1)
elements.remove(R2)
var R3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length),
E3 = elements.slice(R3,1)
elements.remove(R3)
var R4 = Math.floor(Math.random() * elements.length),
E4 = elements.slice(R4,1)
```

The problem is the remove function, it doesn't work when removing a object on a specific location I believe.

Comment: You didn't write this did you? This is exactly the same implementation that John Resig (the creator of jQuery) wrote.

Comment: it is, i found the first part here sorry for not mentioning it, I'm new here

Comment: What should your code do?

Comment: It should give a random id out of 4 to 4 functions but never one double, so basically i'm tring to get different combination of 1 to 4

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are using `elements.slice(R3,1)` wrong. Second argument means not the length of the array you want to get, but the zero-based index of the element when slice method should stop. So your code is saying "Give me elements from index R3 till index 1", and the only one time when it will work: `elements.slice(0, 1)`.
If you just need to get one element - use `elements[R1]`. If you need to get array with one element you can keep using slice with `elements.slice(R1, R1 + 1);`